# Android: location detection by Cellular Network and WiFi

Tags: android, location, android-wifi

I would like to build a app which will provide current location using `cellular Network` and `WiFi`.

I like to get location from both provider simultaneously and then decide which provider give me best.

Now i am getting location from Network

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener locationlistenerforNetwork = new mylocationlistenerNetwork();
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationlistenerforNetwork);

private class mylocationlistenerNetwork implements LocationListener {
      @Override
      public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
          if (location != null) {
          Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLatitude() + " ");
          Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLongitude() + " ");
          Toast.makeText(LocationActivity.this,"latitude: "+
              location.getLatitude() + "longitude: " + location.getLongitude()
              + " Provider:" + location.getProvider() + " Accuracy:" + location.getAccuracy(),
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          }
      }
      @Override
      public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
      }
      @Override
      public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
      }
      @Override
      public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
      }
```

I also want location from `WiFi`. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

There are these providers:

- [GPS_PROVIDER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#GPS_PROVIDER)
- [NETWORK_PROVIDER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#NETWORK_PROVIDER)
- [PASSIVE_PROVIDER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#PASSIVE_PROVIDER)

From docs:

> public static final String NETWORK_PROVIDER
>
> Name of the network location provider. This provider determines
>   location based on availability of **cell tower and WiFi access points**.
>   Results are retrieved by means of a network lookup. Requires either of
>   the permissions android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or
>   android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.

There is no separate provider for WiFi. Using `NETWORK_PROVIDER` you are determining location also base on WiFi access points.