# How to use "only" device GPS and not AGPS in android?

Tags: android, location, android-gps

I have certain requirement within which I need to **use only device GPS** and *not use AGPS at all*, even if it is available on the device.

I presume using the following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

uses both AGPS and device GPS to determine location.

Please guide me through it as I haven't worked much with GPS and location and therefore does not have sound experience in it.

Comment: Note that A-GPS is a different thing from using Wi-Fi APs and cell sites to approximate a location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS)...

> Assisted GPS (abbreviated generally as A-GPS and less commonly as
>   aGPS) is a system that often significantly improves startup
>   performance—i.e., time-to-first-fix (TTFF), of a GPS satellite-based
>   positioning system. A-GPS is extensively used with GPS-capable
>   cellular phones, as its development was accelerated by the U.S. FCC's
>   911 requirement to make cell phone location data available to
>   emergency call dispatchers.

Even though A-GPS may be used to speed up the time-to-first-fix (TTFF), the actual location calculation is done with traditional GPS. Its not that A-GPS is used to determine location but rather to speed up GPS location calculation.

In addition, it would always be preferable to have a short TTFF. I hope you are not confusing this with the network/WiFi derived location. Refer [Location Strategies](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) (note that there is no mention of A-GPS being used to determine the location!) and [Android: location detection by Cellular Network and WiFi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592520/android-location-detection-by-cellular-network-and-wifi).

To my knowledge, the APIs do not provide much control over A-GPS (except sending some commands to clear/request A-GPS data), so may not be possible to disable A-GPS.

Comment: Well, you are probably correct, I was asked to use _only GPS_ to determine location. The requirement may be to prohibit Network (cellular network and WiFi) to determine location. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Like I said in the answer, I don't think that is feasible; at least not programmaticaly by an app alone. Possible if you disable network access in the device/OS.
Just the way Android works...

Answer (score 3):

To disable A-GPS features completely, you need to remove the XTRA and SUPL settings from `/system/etc/gps.conf`. Doing this will require making a custom build of Android unless your device is rooted.

Answer (score -1):

On my Pixel phone running Android 8.0 (beta), I'm able to set the Location Mode in Settings > Security & Location > Location > Mode.

The "Device only" option will make the phone use only GPS to determine location.

Comment: Note that the "Device only" mode will still use XTRA and SUPL (components of A-GPS) to reduce the time-to-first-fix and improve the position. If your application demands no network traffic, or no leaking of position data to the network, then choosing "Device only" is not enough as it merely disables sending the nearby Wi-Fi access points and cell sites to a remote provider to get an approximate location.